# How to use AutoIt to click a window dialog in a different language

Tags: windows, windows-7, autoit

On Windows 7, when we install an unsigned driver, it will pop-up a Windows security dialog. It is easy to have it be clicked on by AutoIt. Just search the window dialog with the specified window title.

But now, I want to use it on another platform with a different language. The window title will be changed to the local language, not the 'Windows security'.

How can I create the AutoIt script, which can handle the Windows security dialog in different language?

Fix this issue by finding a child handle from the security window class.

Comment: Did you try to automate a security dialog? Windows almost always will resist automation because it is a security risk! I doubt you will get this to work in one language, before you worry about several languages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the "[AutoIt v3 Window Information](http://www.autoitscript.com/autoit3/docs/intro/au3spy.htm)" Tool provided by the "AutoIt full installation" and try to get some unique information like a Class name which is occuring in each different language dialog window as descirbed in [advanced window descriptions](http://www.autoitscript.com/autoit3/docs/intro/windowsadvanced.htm). Then use these to search for the proper security window.

I'd suggest, you use the `WinWaitActive("[REGEXPTITLE:Windows Security|Windows Sicherheit]")` function with regular expressions for being able to wait for multiple windows with different titles.

Comment: This is a way. I fixed this issue by find the child handle of this window class.

Answer (score 2):

Try to use a class on Tittle. Title = [CLASS:notepad]

for more information visit here http://autoitsourcecode.blogspot.com/2013/04/autoit-control-send.html